# R - Multiply every row of df or matrix with a vector

Tags: r, data.table, matrix-multiplication

I can't get to make this work, although it seems fairly simple.
I would like to multiply every row in matrix (or dataframe or datatable) b, with vector a.

```
a <- data.table(t(1:4))
b <- matrix(data=2, nrow=3, ncol=4)
```

Desired output (in matrix, dataframe or datatable form):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    6    8  
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    2    4    6    8
```

Can anyone help me how to do this (efficiently)?

Comment: Why is your "vector" `a` a data table here? Is that important? It makes a big difference to how multiplication works when one is a data table. Compare `a * b` with `1:4 * b`, for example. This may be the cause of some of your frustration.

Comment: As it is some data from a .txt file, I have to read this. And I only know how to do this as a data table `fread` or data frame `read_table`. If I can read this like a vector as well, then that would be fine to me.

Comment: If you know its a single-row data table then convert to a vector first.

Comment: Tips for responders: questioner asked for "efficiently" - use `microbenchmark` or other benchmark tools to assess how efficient yours is compared to others; write `my_name=function(a,b){...}` with your solution so it can easily be tested on different data; test on data bigger than 3x4;

Comment: look up the sweep function

Comment: Please post a better example `b` which has different data on each row, otherwise people won't catch errors with indexing, vector-recycling etc. Also, do you want `a` to be a (row) vector, or data.table? It's easier to make `a` a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option#1:** Using `data.table` features:

Note:it works because column number and value matches for `a`

```
a[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(x*b[,x]))]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:  2  4  6  8
#2:  2  4  6  8
#3:  2  4  6  8
```

**Option#2:** could be:

```
t(t(b) * (as.matrix(a)[1,]))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    6    8
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    2    4    6    8
```

**UPDATE**

**Option#3:** To handle decimal/actual values in `a`

```
#Cases when `a` contains decimal values can be handled as
a <- data.table(t(c(1, 0.24, 3, 4)))
b <- matrix(data=2, nrow=3, ncol=4)

a[,lapply(V1:V4,function(i)(a[[i]]*b[,i]))]
#   V1   V2 V3 V4
#1:  2 0.48  6  8
#2:  2 0.48  6  8
#3:  2 0.48  6  8
```

Comment: maybe it's worth mentioning that you're not using matrix multiplication but recycling `a` for an element wise multiplication with `t(b)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like your first solution as it is the fastest one, however I do not completely get how this is sort of looping over the rows of b. Especially the subsetting of b with x `b[,x]` is unclear to me. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: Can you explain why this works:
`a <- data.table(t(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))) ; b <- matrix(data=1, nrow=10, ncol=5) ; a[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(x+b[,x]))]`

but changing the datatable `a` with a decimal, then it doesn't work anymore:
`a <- data.table(t(c(1, 0.2, 3, 4, 5))) ; b <- matrix(data=1, nrow=10, ncol=5) ; a[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(x+b[,x]))]`

Comment: @Z117 That solution was based on multiply `matrix/vector` with single value. It was a slight hack as column number and value in column were matching. For each column single value was passed. If you want that to work with `decimal` values then it should be: `a[,lapply(V1:V4,function(i)(a[[i]]*b[,i]))]`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You are absolutely correct. It was based on  multiply `matrix/vector` with a single value. You solution looks good as well.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Actually, I'm surprise with speed result of my `option#2` that usages `t`.

Comment: I added my own benchmark to my solution with a few additions

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Benchmark analysis is really helpful. Thats gives the true picture. Good work mate.

Answer (score 4):

```
b*rep(unlist(a),each=nrow(b))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    4    6    8
# [2,]    2    4    6    8
# [3,]    2    4    6    8
```

or just `b*rep(a,each=nrow(b))` if you define `a <- 1:4`

It's just a vectorised element wise multiplication with no transformation appart from `rep`.

edit:

It seems that rep is what is slowing down my solution. Here's a benchmark where I include an option with precomputed rep, and some improvements on the sweep option (taking only relevant parts from source code).

```
a <- data.table(t(1:200))
b <- matrix(data=2, nrow=100000, ncol=200)

a_vec <- unlist(a)
rep_a <- rep(a_vec,each=nrow(b))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mkr1 = a[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(x*b[,x]))],
  mkr2 = t(t(b) * (as.matrix(a)[1,])),
  mkr_update = a[,lapply(V1:V4,function(i)(a[[i]]*b[,i]))],
  mm = b*rep(unlist(a),each=nrow(b)),
  mm_cheat = b*rep_a,
  regular_sweep = sweep(b,2,unlist(a),`*`),
  regular_sweep2 = sweep(b,2,a_vec,`*`),
  improved_sweepA1 = b*aperm(array(unlist(a),rev(dim(b)))),
  improved_sweepA2 = b*aperm(array(a_vec,rev(dim(b)))),
  improved_sweepB1 = b*a[rep_len(1,nrow(b)),],
  improved_sweepB2 = b*t(a_vec)[rep_len(1,nrow(b)),],
  unit = "relative",
  times=50)


Unit: relative
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
             mkr1  42.12228  44.15266  50.23959  46.35240  57.20280  65.07289    50
             mkr2 114.58427 124.19653 125.25660 131.08677 124.17058 114.91137    50
       mkr_update   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000    50
               mm 231.34331 223.74365 217.50145 225.91117 215.90765 165.64814    50
         mm_cheat  13.38838  13.22556  14.94682  13.36649  12.95260  25.15564    50
    regular_sweep  96.15758 124.26746 121.04428 128.67282 129.19407 119.20210    50
   regular_sweep2  97.79001 124.69191 124.74650 134.64249 134.97407 107.47152    50
 improved_sweepA1  96.57837 124.86189 116.93736 127.08909 124.92805 105.83318    50
 improved_sweepA2  96.27737 122.49773 118.45262 128.13369 126.15029 106.58669    50
 improved_sweepB1 214.95773 227.39523 226.04339 248.38553 232.50401 161.45341    50
 improved_sweepB2  31.20967  32.61873  37.74552  33.70969  41.52149  55.93362    50
```

Comment: It takes about twice as long as the `sweep` solution on my benchmark for a 75*57 case.

Comment: still, i'm 18 times faster on this small matrix

Comment: For bigger operations `rep` is the reason why it's slower, my solution becomes 7.5 times faster if `rep(a,each=nrow(b)` is precomputed, which is a decent strategy in usecases where the computation needs to be on several matrixes of same dimensions

Answer (score 3):

On my side I would use the built-in method of R for Matrix Multiplication [`%*%`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matmult.html).

Considering the **vector**:  [NB: `data.table` is **not** `vector`]

```
a <- c(1:4)
```

and considering the matrix:

```
b <- matrix(data=2, nrow=3, ncol=4)
```

Your output is given by:

```
output <- b %*% diag(a)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    6    8
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    2    4    6    8
```

#### If you think this solution is very inefficient for your needs, then I suggest to use the built-in function `sweep`:

```
sweep(b, 2, a, FUN = "*")

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    6    8
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    2    4    6    8
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient method since R is doing the full matrix multiply, which means its doing a *lot* of multiply by zero and adding the resulting zero...

Comment: Your point is true but is relevant only for big matrices in the order of millions of rows. In this case, @Z117 did not specify this.

Comment: No. `sweep` is ~four times faster on my test 57*75 matrix, so there's a win even on small matrices. User explicitly specified "efficiency" which I'll equate to speed and memory usage - making a big empty diagonal matrix and then multiplying it out is inefficient both ways.

Comment: it's very intuitive though, so still a valuable solution for interactive use on a small to medium matrix

Comment: looking at `sweep`'s code, it boils down to creating a matrix repeating `a` as rows before multiplying both objects, the return call can be summarized as  `b*aperm(array(a,rev(dim(b))))` which is faster because we skip the overheads, it can be itself optimized into `b*t(a)[rep_len(1,nrow(b)),]` to gain about 30% speed compared to original `sweep`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the replies. I've tested the suggested solutions above on speed (with actual size of my vector and matrix) to use the most efficient one:

```
a <- data.table(t(1:200))
b <- matrix(data=2, nrow=100000, ncol=200)

system.time(sweep(b, MARGIN=2, t(a), "*"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.31    0.06    0.39 

system.time(a[,lapply(.SD,function(x)(x*b[,x]))])
#   user  system elapsed 
#    0.2     0.0     0.2 

#system.time(bind_rows(apply(b,1,`*`,a)))     
#took 100+ so stopped it manually

system.time(t(t(b)*(as.matrix(a)[1,])))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.31    0.05    0.36 

system.time(apply(b, 1, `*`, 1:200))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.20    0.11    1.31 

system.time(b*rep(unlist(a),each=nrow(b)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.83    0.05    0.89 

system.time(b*rep((1:200),each=nrow(b)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.36    0.06    0.42
```

Comment: Good work @Z117. We got some insight info. I'm surprised with speed of my `option#2` which was based on `t`.

Answer (score 1):

```
dplyr::bind_rows(apply(b, 1, `*`, a))
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1:  2  4  6  8
2:  2  4  6  8
3:  2  4  6  8
```

The tricky part is that your `a` is a data.table. If it's actually a vector, then it's much simpler:

```
apply(b, 1, `*`, 1:4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    4    4    4
[3,]    6    6    6
[4,]    8    8    8
```